# best way to inject html using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm hoping that this isn't too subjective. I feel there is a definitive answer so here goes.

I want to create this html on the fly using JS (no libraries):

```
<a href="#" id="playButton">Play</a>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="muteUnmute">Mute</a>
<div id="progressBarOuter"> 
  <div id="bytesLoaded"></div>
    <div id="progressBar"></div>
</div>
<div id="currentTime">0:00</div>
<div id="totalTime">0:00</div>
```

using javascript. I know I can do this using createElement etc but it seems extremely long winded to do this for each element. Can anyone suggest a way to do this with more brevity.

I do not have access to a library in this project....so no jquery etc.

Comment: “I know I can do this using createElement etc but it seems extremely long winded to do this for each element” — yup. When you’ve got repetitive, long-winded programming tasks, you automate that by encapsulating the long-winded bit in a function. When you have a few of those functions that you use regularly, you stick them together, and boom: you’ve got a library! So, time to start writing your own library I think.

Comment: Gen Covid-19 has only one answer to follow-up. Word.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Shove the entire thing into a JS variable:

```
var html = '<a href="#" id="playButton">Play</a>';
html += '<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="muteUnmute">Mute</a>';
html += '<div id="progressBarOuter"><div id="bytesLoaded"></div><div id="progressBar"></div></div>';
html += '<div id="currentTime">0:00</div>';
html += '<div id="totalTime">0:00</div>';
```

Then:

```
document.getElementById("parentElement").innerHTML = html;
```

if you want theN:

```
document.getElementById("totalTime").innerHTML = "5:00";
```

Comment: It's not the nicest solution, but given what the conditions were, it was acceptable.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with this.

Comment: I do it with an array:
var html = []; html.push('<div>'); html.push('</div>')... htmlString = html.join('')...

Comment: @RyanTernier : Recent browsers [don’t parse injected innerHTML](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257243/242800).

Comment: @user2284570 browsers don't parse textContent they do parse innerHTML. That's why it's called innerHTML.

Comment: I'm mildly disturbed no answers or comments mention [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), an official API for parsing XML or HTML source into a DOM Document, which is infinitely more explicit and intentional than `innerHTML` assignment.  (There are historical reasons for avoiding that assignment for deserialization of HTML, mostly surrounding legacy browser memory management, or lack thereof. It's even supported on IE 9.)

Answer (score 33):

**Keep your markup separate from your code:**

You can embed the HTML snippets that you'll be using as hidden templates inside your HTML page and clone them on demand:

```
<style type="text/css">
#templates { display: none }
</style>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
var node = document.getElementById("tmp_audio").cloneNode(true);
node.id = ""; // Don't forget :)
// modify node contents with DOM manipulation
container.appendChild(node);
</script>
...
<div id="templates">
    <div id="tmp_audio">
        <a href="#" class="playButton">Play</a>
        <a href="#" class="muteUnmute">Mute</a>
        <div class="progressBarOuter"> 
            <div class="bytesLoaded"></div>
            <div class="progressBar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="currentTime">0:00</div>
        <div class="totalTime">0:00</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update: Note that I've converted the `id` attributes in the template to `class` attributes. This is to avoid having multiple elements on your page with the same ids. You probably don't even need the classes. You can access elements with:

```
node.getElementsByTagName("div")[4].innerHTML =
    format(data.currentTime);
```

Alternatively, you can act on the HTML of the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tmp = document.getElementById("tmp_audio").innerHTML;
// modify template HTML with token replacement
container.innerHTML += tmp;
</script>
```

Comment: doing it this way will create multiple elements with the same ID,

Comment: @Ryan Ternier: No, it won't. Please note the `node.id = "";` line.

Comment: @Ryan Ternier: Ah I see. You're not talking about the id of the template, but the ids within it. It's just that I copy-pasted the template of the OP. Normally, you wouldn't have ids inside the template. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I am currently doing it like this but this code is for a plugin so i want to use the script to autommate as many things as possible

Comment: @AtesGoral : Recent browsers [don’t parse injected innerHTML](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257243/242800).

Comment: I have seen the KendoUI library wrapping the whole thing in  `<script type="text/x-kendo-template">some_html_content</script>`. In this case the template html will not share the same ID as the copied code.

Comment: Downvoted because [slotted templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots) actually exist now.

Answer (score 14):

If you live in 2019 and beyond read here.

With JavaScript es6 you can use string literals to create templates.

create a function that returns a **string/template literal**

```
function videoPlayerTemplate(data) {
    return `
        <h1>${data.header}</h1>
        <p>${data.subheader}</p>
        <a href="#" id="playButton">Play</a>
        <a href="javascript: void(0)" id="muteUnmute">Mute</a>
        <div id="progressBarOuter"> 
            <div id="bytesLoaded"></div>
            <div id="progressBar"></div>
        </div>
        <time id="currentTime">0:00</time>
        <time id="totalTime">0:00</time>
    `
}
```

Create a JSON object containing the data you want to display

```
var data = {
     header: 'My video player',
     subheader: 'Version 2 coming soon'
}
```

add that to whatever element you like

```
const videoplayer = videoPlayerTemplate(data);
document.getElementById('myRandomElement').insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", videoplayer);
```

You can read more about string literals [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: That's a lovely intro. You just won Stack Overflow pre-Covid and beyond!!

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function appendHTML() {
        var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
        wrapper.innerHTML = '\
<a href="#" id="playButton">Play</a>\
<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="muteUnmute">Mute</a>\
<div id="progressBarOuter"> \
<div id="bytesLoaded"></div>\
    <div id="progressBar"></div>\
</div>\
<div id="currentTime">0:00</div>\
<div id="totalTime">0:00</div>\
';
        document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

edit: HTML import is now [deprecated](https://caniuse.com/#feat=imports).

Now with `Web Components` you can inject HTML using an **HTML import**.

The syntax looks like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="component.html" >
```

This will just load the content of the html file in the `href` attribute inline in the order it appears. You can any valid html in the loaded file, so you can even load other scripts if you want.

To inject that from JavaScript you could do something of the likes of:

```js
var importTag = document.createElement('link');
importTag.setAttribute('rel', 'import');
importTag.setAttribute('href', 'component.html');
document.body.appendChild(importTag);
```

At the time I am writing this, Chrome and Opera support HTML imports. You can see an up to date compatibility table here http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports

But don't worry about browsers not supporting it, you can use it in them anyway with the [webcomponentsjs](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs) polyfill.

For more info about HTML imports check http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-html-imports/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need any validation for your syntax (which is what makes `createElement()` so nice) then you could always default to simply setting the [`innerHTML`](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php) property of the element you want to insert your markup inside of.

Personally, I would stick with using `createElement()`. It is more verbose but there are far less things to worry about that way.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is a concern, stay away from innerHTML.  You should create the whole object tree using `document.createElement()` as many times as needed, including for nested elements.

Finally, append it to the document with one statement, not many statements.

In my informal testing over the years, this will give you the best performance (some browsers may differ).

If HTML is ever declared in a variable, it should be simple and for a very specific purpose. Usually, this is not the right approach.

Comment: Iterative `createElement` is highly under-performant compared to simple bulk deserialization, especially on memory constrained devices such as mobile. Consider: how many forms must your data take before it's usable to the end-user? DB serialization, JSON, JS in-memory, HTML DOM, … [HTML is a data model](https://ghcdn.webcore.io/106548550--73645b--image--the-web-is-already-mvc.png), and it [can be used that way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)!

Answer (score 0):

here's 2 possible cases :

1. Your HTML is static
2. Your HTML is dynamic

### solution 1

In this case, wrap your HTML in **double quotes**, **make it a string** and save it in a  variable. then push it inside HTML, here's a demo

#### HTML

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
let selector = document.querySelector("#test");

let demo_1 = "<div id='child'> hello and welcome</div>"
selector.innerHTML = demo_1;
```

### solution 2

In this case, wrap your HTML in **back ticks**, **make it a template literal** and save it in a  variable. then push it inside HTML,
here, you can use variables to change your content. here's a demo

#### HTML

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
let selector = document.querySelector("#test");

let changes = 'hello and welcome'
let demo_1 = `<div id='child'>${changes}</div>`
selector.innerHTML = demo_1;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can concatenate raw HTML strings (being careful to escape text and prevent XSS holes), or you can rewrite jQuery (or something similar)

Answer (score -1):

I have a situation where I pass text into a third party library, but if my model isPrivate, I'd like to add an element to the text.

```
return { id: item.id, text: (item.isPrivate == true) ? "<i class=\"icon-lock\" title=\"Private group.\"></i> " + item.label : item.label };
```

This creates issues with the way the third party library builds up its markup.

This is never a good idea, but third party libraries are there so that we don't have to write everything ourselves. In a situation like this, you have to rely on passing markup though javascript.

When i find a proper solution to this, I will give you an update

Comment: A [standard library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) exists, too.  Don't always dive for third-party solutions unless you enjoy [left-pad (or is-negative-zero, or is-array, or…) disasters](https://www.davidhaney.io/npm-left-pad-have-we-forgotten-how-to-program/), especially for such fundamental operations.