# Is there an easy way to hook a footer into multiple HTML pages for easy updating?

Tags: html

I am not using Wordpress.  I am simply making a website locally with HTML/CSS/Javascript.  My client has asked me to "add a simple link to the footer navigation" but I have a whole bunch of pages and they're each individual HTML files.

Is there any way to make ONE footer file (while not using CMS systems) and then inject that footer over all these pages with a hook?  That way, I can make one change to one file and have it update all the HTML pages versus changing them all, one by one?

Thank you!!!

Comment: can you use another technology?  E.g., can you use PHP if you want to?

Comment: You can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762385/best-way-to-inject-html-using-javascript for a solution with Javascript. As @ps2goat suggests a PHP include would be a preferred solution if you can use it.

Comment: You could use a static site generator such as Jekyll or Assemble. You would develop in a way that builds pages dynamically, but generates a static site to upload. Depending on the server, you may be able to use old-school SSI (server-side includes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should use the PHP include_once function (providing PHP is installed on your workstation/server).

You would then create a file called footer.php and that file would simply contain the HTML which creates the footer.

Then, on the bottom of each page, remove the HTML footer and add:

```
<?php include_once("footer.php"); ?>
```

That will then include the footer HTML once. Then, when you make an edit to the footer.php file, the change will show site-wide.

Comment: Perfect!  This was exactly what I was looking for.  That said, is there any downfall to using a PHP include?  For example, I'm planning on pulling in my header, my global scripts and global css as well as my footer...and anything else that appears redundantly across pages.

Also, is there a difference between include and include_once? Or is it just shorthand to place <?php include (); ?>

Thanks again, James!

Comment: @BirdieGolden include_once simply means that if the code from the included file has already been included within the same PHP script, it will not be included. In this case, it's really not going to make a different. Just use <?php include("path/to/file.php"); ?> where you want your header, footer, etc to be included. By the way, there's no downfalls to using the include function.

Comment: @BirdieGolden to help future viewers, you should accept the answer that was of most use to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would not advise it, but you could do it with JavaScript: create a JavaScript file with the function which writes footer. You still would need to include the JavaScript file and the function call on every page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably going to get some hate for this and **I highly don't suggest this route**, but if you don't want to go through the whole loading through JS route and you know the dimensions of your footer, you can use an iframe.

Comment: Thanks Birdman.  It's good to know my options.  Unfortunately, the dimensions change a little because the website is responsive and formats to mobile devices, so I'm not sure this solution would entirely work...but thank you regardless :D