# How to Inject HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

**Solution**
My question was asked with little knowledge in HTML and JavaScript, I apologize for this. With more experience I can clearly see that this was not a good question asked, anyway the solution to my own question can be found here:
[best way to inject html using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762385/best-way-to-inject-html-using-javascript).

**Problem:**
I am trying to show the whole list in HTML. For instance, if there are three names, I want the names to be shown in between `<td>...</td>`. Is there a way I can extract all this list to HTML via JavaScript?

I know I need an array and probably a for loop. Maybe I am thinking too complex.

**Here is the HTML code:**

```
<table class = "table table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Full Name</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr id = "scoreList">
      <tr>....</tr>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**Here is the JavaScript code:**

```
// Loop through customers
for( var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
    var k = keys[i]; 
   // var id = customers[k].id;
    var name = customers[k].name;

    // Add code here to show list of names in html 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use no frameworks, that's one easy way to do it:

```
// Generate the <td>'s.
const rendered = keys.map((v) => `<td>${v}</td>`).join('');
// Write them on the screen.
document.getElementById('scoreList').getElementsByTag('tr')[0].innerHTML = rendered;
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure javascript (and assuming you'll want the `<td>` elements in `<tr>` elements) you can use this.

```js
var customers = [
  {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'William',
    lastName: 'Shakespear'
  }
]

for(var customer of customers) {
  var tdFN = document.createElement('TD');
  tdFN.innerHTML = customer.firstName;
  
  var tdLN = document.createElement('TD');
  tdLN.innerHTML = customer.lastName;
  
  var tr = document.createElement('TR');
  tr.appendChild(tdFN);
  tr.appendChild(tdLN);
  
  document.querySelector('table.table.table-striped tbody').appendChild(tr);
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Full Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="scoreList">
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```