# D3 app: creating input toolbars programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, d3.js, flask

Shorter question: how should toolbars be programatically created and dynamically changed in a D3.js app with a Python backend?

I'm trying to create Javascript/D3 visualizations for simulations written in Python and using Flask, as an alternative to using a Tkinter GUI. I want a particular model to be selected by a radio button. Changing the selection not only changes the plot, but also swaps to a toolbar of numerical inputs appropriate for that model. I want to create the toolbars programatically, so that as a new model is added to the code an appropriate toolbar is automatically generated.

My problem is that there are a lot of ways to manipulate the DOM, and it's not clear to me what the best approach would be:

- Python/Flask could manipulate the DOM, but I think that requires a
  page refresh.
- If HTML imports were used, there would have to be a separate .html file for each toolbar.
- A unique `<div>` could be created for each toolbar and hidden/unhidden as needed, but it feels wrong to create a dozen `<div>`s rather than swap the content of one `<div>`.
- A toolbar `<div>` could be torn down/built up everytime a toolbar is needed, but it feels wrong to keep building the same toolbars from scratch.
- innerHTML could be swapped, but this might be bad? cf. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762385/best-way-to-inject-html-using-javascript)
- There are multiple options for manipulating the DOM at the frontend: JS, D3, JQuery...

To illustrate, here is a screenshot of what I have so far. The radio buttons swap between two models. In lieu of a toolbar, I have a JSON dump of the model's toolbar info. The JSON dump would be replaced by its interpretation as a series of labels and numerical inputs.

[image]

Comment: This question is inappropriate for stack overflow and will probably be closed as "primarily opinion based".  That said, if I was coding it your last option would be my approach.