# Dynamically rendering a range slider in javascript in Framework7

Tags: javascript, forms, html-framework-7, rangeslider

I would like to render a range slider dynamically using Javascript (attaching it to the div `emptypage` in a `Framework7` mobile app application.

First I tried to add a simple text element, which works (I am sorry I cannot find the source author of this piece of code anymore to give proper credit).

```
var div = document.getElementById('emptypage');
var form = document.createElement('form');
var input1 = document.createElement('input');
input1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
input1.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Name');
input1.setAttribute('name', 'routename');
input1.setAttribute('id', 'rname');
form.appendChild(input1);
div.appendChild(form);
```

However, after I changed the code in...

```
var div = document.getElementById('emptypage');
var form = document.createElement('form');
var input1 = document.createElement('input');
input1.setAttribute('id', 'test');
input1.setAttribute('type', 'range');
input1.setAttribute('min', 0);
input1.setAttribute('max', 100);
input1.setAttribute('step', 1);
input1.setAttribute('value', 50);
form.appendChild(input1);
div.appendChild(form);
```

... I see that the slider is added to the `Framework7` html file, but the slider is not rendered (displayed) on the page.

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

PS. I tried the method that was proposed by @ii iml0sto1 here @ [best way to inject html using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762385/best-way-to-inject-html-using-javascript) , but that did not work either.

PPS. The solution proposed by @Amit Mondal did not work either. My guess is that is is caused by `Framework7`? So I updated my question to include references to this framework.

PPPS. Other types of input elements (text and drop-down questions) are rendered properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue and asked the same question on the forum.

The trick is to use the init AFTER you've added your DOM.

So create your DOM as you would normally and then use this code:

```
var range = app.range.create({
  el: '.range-slider',
  on: {
    change: function () {
      console.log('Range Slider value changed')
    }
  }
});
```

`.range-slider` is the class of the slider element.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the code snippet below

```js
var div = document.getElementById('emptypage');
var form = document.createElement('form');

var input1 = document.createElement('input');
input1.setAttribute('id', 'test');
input1.setAttribute('type', 'range');
input1.setAttribute('min', 0);
input1.setAttribute('max', 100);
input1.setAttribute('step', 1);
input1.setAttribute('value', 50);

var value = document.createElement('p');
value.setAttribute('id', 'sliderValue');
value.innerHTML = input1.value;

form.appendChild(input1);
div.appendChild(form);
div.appendChild(value);

// To update the slider value dynamically
input1.oninput = function() {
  value.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id='emptypage'>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work. I guess I it has something to do with my application (Framework7 for hybrid apps). If I found the issue I'll let you know; also I will update my question.

Comment: I hope this helps you a bit https://framework7.io/docs/range-slider.html

Comment: Thanks, but no I cannot see how the framework7 apis can help here. Do you? (PS. I can render text and other input fields without any issues).