# What is the correct way of adding elements into injected HTML?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dynamics-365

We are in the process of phasing out custom forms (created in React) on our website, and replacing them with Microsoft Dynamics 365 generated forms.

These forms are injected via a React placeholder component created by a script to load the js bundle and loaded into the DOM by the code below, as they are created in Dynamics 365 the structure is handled in the form builder.

```
React.createElement(d365mktforms.FormPlaceholder, {
            formId: '14299349-****-****-****-*******cde50335',
            formApiBaseUrl: 'https://public-apj.mkt.dynamics.com/api/v1.0/orgs/****c3d6-****-****-a87b-5f737234ce93/landingpageforms',
            formUrl: 'https://assets-apj.mkt.dynamics.com/****3d6-****-****-a87b-5f737234****/digitalassets/forms/1429****-****-****-8847-000d3aa0****',
        }, 'contactForm')
```

We want to retain the custom validation and styling currently used for the custom forms. This includes adding an event listeners for all email fields and making an API request for validation, and displaying validation messages in labels underneath the fields like so:

[image]

These labels don't exist in the Microsoft generated forms, so I need to create them on the fly or on a "form loaded" event. I can do this pretty easily using JavaScript and modifying the DOM, however I know this goes against the purpose of React.

Is there a correct way of fetching creating a React element and adding them into the injected HTML elements?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [best way to inject html using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762385/best-way-to-inject-html-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Adding DOM Container To The HTML. First, open the HTML page that you want to change.

Step 2: Add The Script Tags Or React Tags. Next, you have to add three `<script>` tags to the HTML page right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Step 3: Create A React Component.

And there is fourth way to do it [here](https://gomakethings.com/four-different-ways-to-inject-text-and-html-into-an-element-with-vanilla-javascript/).

And there is another way:

```js
var html = '<a href="#" id="playButton">Play</a>';
html += '<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="muteUnmute">Mute</a>';
html += '<div id="progressBarOuter"><div id="bytesLoaded"></div><div id="progressBar"></div></div>';
html += '<div id="currentTime">0:00</div>';
html += '<div id="totalTime">0:00</div>';
```